# Changing the name value of a text field using next()

Tags: jquery

Via jQuery I'm trying to change the name value of the hidden field. There are a lot of these section html elements so I'm trying to do it like this and it wont work

```
<section>
    People:
    <div data-score-name="people" class="options">
        <img src="star-on.png" alt="1" title="bad">
        <img src="star-on.png" alt="2" title="poor">
        <img src="star-on.png" alt="3" title="regular">
        <img src="star-half.png" alt="4" title="good">
        <img src="star-off.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous">
        <input type="hidden" name="score[]" value="3.5">
    </div>
</section>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var ScoreName = $(this).attr('data-score-name');
$('.options').next().attr('name', 'score[' + ScoreName + ']');
```

Am i typing it wrong?

the error i'm getting via firebug is:

```
TypeError: $(...).next(...).attr(...) is undefined
```

**Update**: I solved this by just doing

```
var ScoreName = $(this).attr('data-score-name');
     $(this).append("<input type='hidden' name='rate[" + ScoreName + "]' value='" + score + "'>");
```

ps: sorry if i was vague in anyway i was just in a rush, i'll come back to update this regarding the raty rating system so that anyone else who comes along it'll help them as well.

Comment: would you submit full code please ? what does this refer to ?

Comment: esentally its the full code, the end results of what i am trying to do is change <input type="hidden" name="score[]" value="3.5"> to <input type="hidden" name="score[people]" value="3.5">

Comment: there are some traversing issues in the code... other than that it is fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MuN7P/1/

Comment: Uhm, is there a next() element, the div seems to be the last element inside the section, which would be easier to notice with proper indentation.

Comment: i'm using jqueryies raty rating system and was just trying to figure out a way to give a name for the hidden field that it creates including the actual name of the rate. I am using more than 1 rating thing on a page, the library can be found here: http://wbotelhos.com/raty#score

Answer (score 1):

As there's no other input fields you can access like this:

```
$('.options').next('input').attr('name', 'score[' + ScoreName + ']');
```

Or like this would be better:

```
$('.options').next('input[name="score[]"').attr('name', 'score[' + ScoreName + ']');
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this jQuery is put inside an event handler somehow? I'll demonstrate how to change that value with a click handler for demo sake:

```
$('div.options').click(function() {
    var scoreName = $(this).data('score-name'); // same as .attr('data-score-name');
    var newName = 'score[' + ScoreName + ']';
    $(this).find('input[name="score[]"]').attr('name', newName);
});
```

In the case where you say you have many `section` elements with these hidden fields, you really need to use `this` to help target the correct input, as in your question you're using the **class name** as a selector, so there will be many possible results.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use :

```
$("input[name='score[]'").attr("name","score[people]")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/ffLCd/1/

just in case u meant people to be a dynamic value :

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/ffLCd/3/